# get day of the week from yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: datetime

I would like to convert a yyyy-mm-dd to something like this:

"Saturday, 2 October 2009"

I would like also to have the option to modify the language both day of the week and month (make it customizable)

thanks in advance ;)

Comment: What language/framework are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming .NET (from the datetime tag):

```
DateTime.Parse("2009-10-02").ToString("D", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en"));
```

Answer (score 7):

Since you never told us the language, [here](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Cobol-1443/2008/6/COBOL-5.htm)'s a discussion on how to do it in COBOL.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you would use a combination of the `localtime()` and `strftime()` functions. They should handle internationalization more or less automatically, if your application is set up for it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date into an integer, representing the days since a specific date, then add a number and apply the modulus operator with the operand 7. That will give you a number 0-6 that represents the day of week.

However, most languages have this functionality built-in.