# MM-DD-YYYY to day of week, analyzing consecutive working days

Tags: excel, datetime, vba

I'm analyzing data based on x consecutive working days, M-F (and later skipping selected holidays).  My plan is to take MM-DD-YYYY and determine the day of the week.

How can I do this in VBA?

I found this simple way using .NET but how do I call from Office 2007 VBA, and what reference do I need to add?

> DateTime.Parse("2009-10-02").ToString("D",
>   CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en")
>   [.NET Day of week from YYYY-MM-DD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692712/get-day-of-the-week-from-yyyy-mm-dd)

For completeness and to help others, here is how my code ended up:
**How can I cleanly generalize this for x days look forward**?

```
        myDateStd = myDate
        If Right(Left(myDate, 2), 1) = "/" Then myDateStd = "0" & myDate   'IF M/*/YYYY
        If Len(myDateStd) = 9 Then myDateStd = Left(myDateStd, 3) & "0" & Right(myDateStd, 6) ' If MM/D/YYYY' fix
        dayNumber = Weekday(DateSerial(Right(myDateStd, 4), Left(myDateStd, 2), Mid(myDateStd, 4, 2)), vbMonday)

        Select Case dayNumber
            Case 1 To 3
                workingDaysDelta = 3
            Case 4 To 5      'i.e. its a Friday (or thur) so need to count Fri,S,S,M,T
                workingDaysDelta = 5
            Case 6 To 7     ' its sat/sun
                workingDaysDelta = 4
            Case Else
                MsgBox "ERROR date seams invalid, Date = " & myDateStd
        End Select

'Loop with If testing conditions including:
CDate(wbAn.Cells(j, "E")) < (CDate(myDate) + dayNumber)
```

Comment: Have you considered SQL as well as VBA?

Comment: @Remou: what does this have to do with SQL or databases? neither is mentioned in the question

Comment: Apologies, I had thought that Access was mentioned. However, it still may be useful to consider SQL for analysis by day of the week, depending on the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of the following should work

**numeric, e.g. 2**

```
Weekday(DateSerial(Right(s, 4), Left(s, 2), Mid(s, 4, 2)), vbMonday)
```

**short string, e.g. "Tue"**

```
Format(DateSerial(Right(s, 4), Left(s, 2), Mid(s, 4, 2)), "ddd")
```

**long string, e.g. "Tuesday"**

```
Format(DateSerial(Right(s, 4), Left(s, 2), Mid(s, 4, 2)), "dddd")
```

where `s` is the string containing the date in `'MM-DD-YYYY'` format.

There is no need to add any references.

Comment: @AdamRalph I think that you may be making this a little complicated by declaring s as a string, rather than suggesting that the date is stored as a date/time in a table.

Comment: @Remou - ok, I've edited to try and make it as clear as possible ;-).  Btw - I don't see what this has to do with a 'table'.

Comment: Apologies, I had thought that Access was mentioned.

Comment: Looks good please note that the code example line 1, returns 1 for a monday date not the 2.  [us test system]